# Symfony 2 - How to edit radio button group

Tags: symfony, radio-button, twig

Hi I'm new to Symfony and I have the following problem:

I'm implementing a rate form so I added a radio button group so select a value from 1 to 5.
The idea is yo show five stars instead of the classic radio buttons so I need to add a class to
each input field.

The problem is that symfony adds the class to the hole radio group and not each input.

I searched for a solution and the closest hint I found was this:

```
{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% for child in form %}
            {{ form_widget(child, {'attr': {'class': 'rating-input'}}) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

The code above also wraps the radio group on a div with the class 'rating-input'.

This is the test form code in the controller:

```
$form->createFormBuilder()
     ->add('rate', 'choice', array(1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4, 5 => 5), 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false))
     ->add('save', 'submit')
     ->getForm();
```

Here's a sample image of the html I got:
[image]
Any ideas how can I achieve what I want?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok here's what I did.
I used form theming to override the way each input is displayed.
To do that you have to add a "form_theme form self" tag and override the choice_widget block in your twig where the form is to be rendered.

```
{% extends ::base.html.twig %}

{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% for child in form %}
            {{ form_widget(child, {'attr': 'star'}) }}
            {{ form_label(child) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks anyway for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Easier than all this would be to simply loop through the individual radio buttons:

```
{% for radioRate in form.rate %}
    {{ form_widget(radioRate, {'attr': 'star'}) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is several possible solutions:

### jQuery

See this [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/teG9C/). Move your mouse pointer on the stars, then click on the last star.

The ideas are:

1. Add 5 `<span>` elements containing each one star
2. Set a value from 1 to 5 to each `<span>`
3. When the cursor hovers a `<span>`, color all the previous `<span>` in Gold
4. When clicking a star, get the value of the `<span>` and change the `<select>` value
5. When leaving the box, display as many stars as the value of `<select>` (without this, you can click on the third star, hover 5 stars, leave the box and the `<select>` will have a different value (3) than the number of stars displayed (5))

You can hide the `<select>` element. In fact, it should not be a problem to change the type of input (radio, select, numeric field, etc.).

Edit: [jsffidle with same stars modifying values of `<input type="radio">`](http://jsfiddle.net/b25aV/2/).

## Old solution:

### Styling each value

Why do you want to add some classes to your radio `<label>`s?

You can add some style to the `<label>`s with CSS, for example:

```css
label[for=tag_rate_0] {
    color:Green;
}
label[for=tag_rate_1] {
    color:Red;
}
label[for=tag_rate_2] {
    color:Blue;
}
label[for=tag_rate_3] {
    color:Orange;
}
label[for=tag_rate_4] {
    color:Purple;
}
```

See this example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b25aV/). `label[for=tag_rate_0]` correspond to the `1` score, this is due to the way Symfony2 count fields.

### Displaying stars

You can also display 1 to 5 stars by modifying your form:

```php
->add('rate', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        1 => '*',
        2 => '**',
        3 => '***',
        4 => '****',
        5 => '*****'
    ),
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => false
))
```

It will display `*` to `*****` for the scores. See this example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b25aV/1/).

### jQuery UI

The button widget can be use to [display a nice choice widget](http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio). See this example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUUAs/1/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. What I want is to display the radio buttons as stars not the labels. As you explained in your answer displaying the stars in the labels is quite easy. My problem is that symfony sets the class I use for displaying the stars to the group of radios and not each one of them. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an image of what you want.

Comment: Do you use jQuery on your webite? You can use it to add any class you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does what I need, but is there a way to do the same with radio buttons instead of select and choice tags? I have to stick to the designer's code and they must be radios. Sorry for the inconvenience.